# Reproducing a reverb/echo

Tags: reverb, echo

This question is pretty specific so i'm not sure if this question will be appreciated or not, apologies if not.

Let's start with a little background:

I'm trying to record my voice and and using Fruity Loops 10 to achieve a certain 'sound'.
The voice in question i'm trying to mimic is this one:

Now i have been able to mimic the overal voice using the 'Blur' function.

The problem i'm facing:
If you listen closely at the beginning of each of his sentences you will hear an echo-like sound. I've been trying to reproduce this with the convolution reverb function. but it sounds more like i'm inside a church then his voice actually echo'ing.

My specifics using the reverb option in Fruity Loops 10/ Edison:

Delay: -5% (From midle)
Dry: 100%
Wet: 10%

Am i looking at the wrong function, perhaps this is featured in a plugin?

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Just to clarify, I think this is actually a great question for this site. Specific questions like these can get better, more precise answers. Plus, I think it's an interesting question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That effect is called Backwards Reverb - the simplest way to do it is to reverse the waveform, then add a normal reverb, then reverse it again.

Many DAW's have a backwards reverb plugin which effectively does exactly this, but without you having to do the reversing manually, but I don't think Fruity Loops has this.

I did find [this tutorial](http://onestophiphop.forumotion.com/t8-how-to-make-reverse-reverb-in-fruity-loops) specific to Fruity Loops.

Comment: So that's how they do it! Nice work Dr. Mayhem, always curious about this one.

Comment: Thanks Dr, that's exactly what i was looking for!
+1 for including aditional information regarding the question.